# nginx configuration root

Tags: nginx, configuration-files

Help me to configure nginx index file option, please.
Any requests except the main page i want to redirect to some handler file and the main page request to index.html file.

Something like this:

```
example.com/123/ -> /root/handler.php
example.com/123.php -> /root/handler.php
example.com/ -> /root/index.html
```

### **Answer**

i use this config

```
listen   80;
    server_name domain.com;
    root /srv/http/domain.com;
    index index.html;

    charset utf-8;
    access_log  /var/log/http/x_nginx_access.log  main;
    error_log   /var/log/http/x_nginx_error.log  warn;

    auth_basic "Restricted access";
    auth_basic_user_file /srv/http/$host/.htpasswd;

    location = / {
            index index.html;
    }

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /handler.php?$args;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
            expires 24h;
            log_not_found off;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny  all;
    }

    location ~ \.php {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Request-Filename $request_filename;

            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/http/$host$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING    $query_string;

            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

            proxy_read_timeout 512;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have problems with it?